# Add a custom prefix to a library in gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, g++

I am working with gcc and i have this library that is included using `-I/usr/include/mylib/` and I want to be able to include it using

```
#include <mylib/header.hpp>
```

but when i use the above command i am only able to use it like this

```
#include <header.hpp>
```

How to add a custom prefix to an already included library like mentioned before?

Comment: You want to put the directory containing `mylib` on the inlcude path instead of `mylib` itself. Is using `-I/usr/include` instead of `-I/usr/include/mylib` an option?

Comment: Yes that would solve it. But including the whole /usr/include messes with my project.

Comment: That sounds odd. In what way does `/usr/include` mess with your project? Also, is `mylib` something you installed manually? Generally users shouldn't touch `/usr` themselves. So if that's the case, installing `mylib` to a different prefix like `/usr/local/` or `~/.local/` or `/opt` might help

Comment: It messes it because I am using multiple library from another custom directory and when I include /usr/lib some libraries got redefinition error. 
Also, I want to avoid reinstalling the library to a new directory.

Comment: Could you add details about precisely errors you're encountering when those directories are on the include path? `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib` are both default search directories (see e.g. `cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null`). If having those directories on the search path creates problems, there may be something seriously wrong with your system or project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: as far as I know: no, such an option doesn't exist.

But I think your question raises a few points that might lead to the root cause of the issue you want to solve.

If including `/usr/include` messes up the project, this could indicate that f.e. you try to cross compile or simply the names of the header files in your project should have a prefix or generally unique name to avoid the conflict.

As managing dependencies can be tedious, a build system would be recommended for any none trivial project. I would suggest CMake out of the popular ones I have used on Linux (automake, make, qmake, meson, ...). This makes it a lot easier to declare these dependencies.

Do you have control over mylib? A common way to install headers for libraries is by adding another directory in between (that could also include the epoch / major version):

```
/use/include/mylib-1.0/mylib/header.hpp
```

Typically `pkg-config`, or CMake's `find_package` would be used to add the include path `/use/include/mylib-1.0` and the required linker flags for `mylib`.

Is installing the library in a different path a viable approach? Where does `mylib` come from? Why do you have to use the library installed under `/usr/include`?

Is creating a folder with a link to `mylib` feasible? So that `/usr/include/mylib-X/mylib` links to `/usr/include/mylib`? That way you could use the include path `/usr/include/mylib-X` and have all the header files prefixed:

```
#include <mylib/header.hpp>
```

You could also f.e. create a folder `external` within your project and add a symbolic link to `/usr/include/mylib` into the folder `external/mylib-X/`.

However, this would be a none standard approach. It depends if you want a standard solution and be able to distribute the result easily or just compile on your machine.